# Best enviorment for Node.js on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have Node.js server Application that receive data via `SerialPort` and serve it in `Express`.

I have tried couple of Operating system to install Node.js and I have found none fit to my desire.

I'm looking for OS that can easly installed and have SSH keys interface like `Ubunto SSO`, I have tried already `Ubunto Core` and its almost imposibble to install Node.js with `Snap`, I have also tried `Raspbian` and it was trouble to set all setting manualy.

I am looking for something quick and clean like Ubunto Core but with the classic commands(No snap).

I am trying to install `Ubunto Server` Right now and I hope it will fit perfectly, if you guys have something to recommend for me, it will be very useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up here, it's Ubuntu.

As for your node issue, currently I'd recommend Raspbian for the simple reason that it's based off Debian. You can find a Node installation guide [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). As for setting up SSH you'll just need to install the server with `apt install openssh-server`. I wouldn't really know much about easily installing SSH keys, but Google will always be your friend.